# WPF MVVM Enable\Disable telerik:RadComboBox inside GridViewDataColumn from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, radgridview, isenabled

In WPF, I am trying to disable combo boxes inside a telerik:GridViewDataColumn based on the IsComboBoxEnabled property of my ViewModel.  If I set IsEnabled=false from XAML, it works and the combo box is disabled.  However, when I bind IsEnabled to a value on my viewmodel, it is always enabled even when the value is set to false.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SomeSelectedValue}" 
                                                 ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemsSource}" 
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboBoxEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

```
public bool IsComboBoxEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return _isComboBoxEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        _isComboBoxEnabled = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsComboBoxEnabled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to me setting the IsComboBoxEnabled property from the viewmodel of the datagrid instead of the viewmodel of the individual record.